# Is it possible to add memberUid as bind DN

Tags: ldap, openldap, pam-ldap, ldapsearch, ldapmodule

Can we use memberUid for bind dn string.

Here is my sample ldif file

```
dn: cn=posixgroup,dc=memtesting,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
gidNumber: 1001
cn: posixgroup
memberUid: posixuser

dn: cn=posixuser,cn=posixgroup,dc=memtesting,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: uidObject
cn: posixuser
uid: posixuser
sn: posixuser
userPassword: posixuser123
```

Thanks & Regards,
Ram

Comment: (a) You can only use existing distinguished names as values for your bind DN, and (b) memberUid doesn't uniquely identify anything, so it wouldn't make sense as a DN in any case.

Comment: @larsks, Do you have any justification document? I had read the schema file there they were saying memerUid is case-sensitive it seems to be unique for me.

Comment: `memberUid` isn't unique at all -- it's a multi-valued attribute representing the members of a group. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, in which case an example and/or links to the documentation you're reading might help.